# Android action bar won't show up

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Hello currently implementing the action bar on my android app.

Trying to add this overflow image.

[image]

I am trying to follow the official documentation. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Adding

However, when I run my app my screen shows up like this without the image for the actionbar

[image]

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

**This is my main.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >



    <item android:id="@+id/action_overflow"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

**This is my java code for the MainActivity.java**

```
package com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app;

import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.triggertrap.seekarc.SeekArc;
import com.triggertrap.seekarc.SeekArc.OnSeekArcChangeListener;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private SeekArc mSeekArc;
    private SeekBar mRotation;
    private SeekBar mStartAngle;
    private SeekBar mSweepAngle;
    private SeekBar mArcWidth;
    private SeekBar mProgressWidth;
    private CheckBox mRoundedEdges;
    private CheckBox mTouchInside;
    private CheckBox mClockwise;
    private TextView mSeekArcProgress;

    private Button block_button_text;
    private Button security_settings_button_text;
    private Button blacklist_whitelist_button_text;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.merge);

        //Editing Button Text

        block_button_text = (Button)findViewById(R.id.block_button);
        block_button_text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/roboto-light.ttf"));

        security_settings_button_text = (Button)findViewById(R.id.security_settings_button);
        security_settings_button_text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/roboto-light.ttf"));

        blacklist_whitelist_button_text = (Button)findViewById(R.id.blacklist_whitelist_button);
        blacklist_whitelist_button_text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/roboto-light.ttf"));







        mSeekArc = (SeekArc) findViewById(R.id.seekArc);
        mSeekArcProgress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seekArcProgress);
        mRotation = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.rotation);
        mStartAngle = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.startAngle);
        mSweepAngle  = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sweepAngle);
        mArcWidth = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.arcWidth);
        mProgressWidth = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.progressWidth);
        mRoundedEdges = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.roundedEdges);
        mTouchInside = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.touchInside);
        mClockwise = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.clockwise);

       mRotation.setProgress(mSeekArc.getArcRotation());
       mStartAngle.setProgress(mSeekArc.getStartAngle());
       mSweepAngle.setProgress(mSeekArc.getSweepAngle());
       mArcWidth.setProgress(mSeekArc.getArcWidth());
       mProgressWidth.setProgress(mSeekArc.getProgressWidth());






        mSeekArc.setOnSeekArcChangeListener(new OnSeekArcChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekArc seekArc) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekArc seekArc) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekArc seekArc, int progress,
                                          boolean fromUser) {
                mSeekArcProgress.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            }
        });

        mRotation.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar view, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                mSeekArc.setArcRotation(progress);
                mSeekArc.invalidate();
            }
        });

        mStartAngle.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar view, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                mSeekArc.setStartAngle(progress);
                mSeekArc.invalidate();
            }
        });

        mSweepAngle.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar view, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                mSeekArc.setSweepAngle(progress);
                mSeekArc.invalidate();
            }
        });

        mArcWidth.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar view, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                mSeekArc.setArcWidth(progress);
                mSeekArc.invalidate();
            }
        });

        mProgressWidth.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar view, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                mSeekArc.setProgressWidth(progress);
                mSeekArc.invalidate();
            }
        });

        mRoundedEdges.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
                mSeekArc.setRoundedEdges(isChecked);
                mSeekArc.invalidate();
            }
        });

        mTouchInside.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
                mSeekArc.setTouchInSide(isChecked);
            }
        });

        mClockwise.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
                mSeekArc.setClockwise(isChecked);
                mSeekArc.invalidate();
            }
        });

    }



}
```

Comment: What theme if your app using?

Comment: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">

Comment: which part of the actionbar you want to put it??4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the xml-file with the onCreateOptionsMenu method in your activity

For example:

menu1.xml (save this xml-file in res/menu)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/item1"
      android:icon="@drawable/xyz"
      android:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Now load the xml file like this:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
   MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu1, menu);
   return true;
}
```

Comment: unexpected end of file of the xml? or I probably have to just edit my java code

Comment: I also get inflate(int,menu) cannot in MenuInflater cannot be applied to (int)

Answer (score 0):

Try and see this method: Call this one in your OnCreate(),

```
private void getOverflow() {

    try {
       ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
       Field menuKey = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
       if(menuKey != null) {
           menuKey.setAccessible(true);
           menuKey.setBoolean(config, false);
       }
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
 }
```